# Mapping of permuted arrays

Tags: javascript, algorithm, google-maps, mapping, permutation

I have 3 Sets/Arrays. 2 of them are permutated for a number n ∈ {1,2,3,4} (eg n = 4 -> ABCD) and the 3rd one is a comibination of 2 elements. Here are the permutated sets A and B (they are identical):

> ABCD ABDC ACBD ACBD ACDB ADBC ADCB BACD BADC BCAD BCDA BDAC BDCA CABD
>   CADB CBAD CBDA CDAB CDBA DABC DACB DBAC DBCA DCAB DCBA

And here the set with the Combination for n ∈ {1,2,3,4} (eg n = 4 -> AA AB AC AD...):

> AA AB AC AD BA BB BC BD CA CB CC CD DA DB DC DD

So this is the input.

**Mapping of the 3 Sets/Arrays**

I want to combine those 3 Sets/Arrays, without comparing the content of each object, to get an output as follows:

> [ABCD DA ABCD][ABCD DA ABDC][ABCD DA ACBD][ABCD DA ACDB][ABCD DA
>   ADBC][ABCD DA ADCB]....

For the first elements of set A. So the last character of the first element of set A is mapped with the first character of the combination and the second character of the combination is mapped with the first character of all the elements from set B.

This has to be done with all Elements.

The tricky part is, that n is not static and is set as 1, 2, 3 or 4. So i need a function which takes this into account.

**After the mapping**

Each Element of the Sets is an object, which describes a route. That object is as follow:

```
originRoute = { 
  a: google.maps.LatLng, 
  b: google.maps.LatLng, 
  c: google.maps.LatLng, 
  d: google.maps.LatLng, 
  distance: integer }; //Element of Set A
destinationRoute = {
  a': google.maps.LatLng,
  b': google.maps.LatLng,
  c': google.maps.LatLng,
  d': google.maps.LatLng,
  distance: integer }; //Element of Set B
connectionRoute = {
  originPeer: google.maps.LatLng,
  destinationPeer: google.maps.LatLng,
  distance: integer }; //Element of Combination
```

After Mapping the Routes A, B, C I want to calculate the shortest distance from a' to d'. But to achieve this, i need to map those elements.

Can anyone give me a hind how to achieve that, by taking into account the size of each array can varry with the given n.

Comment: I'm not sure what you've done, and what you're asking.  Can you generate the permutations and combinations?  And you just need to get the `(n!)^2` items in the output?  My first thought would be to iterate through the two permutation lists, and choose the unique combination that chains the permutation together.

Comment: This is what ive done finaly. I just iterated trough the two permutation list and chained it wit the connector.